# How to add custom attributes on a series of elements depending on their index number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of `div` elements that I want to add a custom attribute depending on their index number with `jQuery`

Here is my code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').each(function() {
    $('.block').attr('order', ($('.block').index() + 1).toString()); // not sure what to add
    // console.log(($('.block').index() + 1).toString());
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: powderblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
```

I am trying to add an attribute `order` and it's value to it's corresponding index number. But I always get the same number inside the loop. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always using the whole set of selected objects for each iteration, use the current object within the handler of the function `$.each()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Use the param index
  $('.block').each(function(index) {
    // The context `this` points to a specific element.
    $(this).attr('order', index + 1);
    console.log($(this).attr('order'));
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: powderblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder everything could be improved! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, `$(this)` is what I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [the callback version of `attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function):

```
$('.block').attr('order', function(index) {
  return index;
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').attr('order', function(index) {
    return index;
  });
  // Showing it worked:
  $('.block').each(function(index) {
    console.log("index = " + index + ", order = " + $(this).attr("order"));
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: powderblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` inside the `each` loop instead of setting the order attribute for all of the `.block` elements. Also, instead of adding an `order` attribute, you should use data attributes instead and use `data-order`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-order', i+1); 
  });
  $('.block').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).data('order'));
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: powderblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using order as a attribute you can use data-* attributes features.This is the recommended way of adding custom data.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.block').each(function(index) {
        $(this).data('order', index + 1);
        console.log($(this).data('order'));
      })
    });
```

```css
.block {
  background: powderblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
<div class='block'></div>
```